# decryption of block cipher?

Tags: c++, cryptography

Hi i have encrypted a data of size 196,662 bytes, using block cipher method AES-128 of mode electronic code book (ecb), and now the encrypted data size became 196,672 bytes. And now I have to decrypt, since the data size i have to decrypt is a multiple of 16, I tried decrypting the encrypted data at a single stretch without dividing it, but its not decrypting. Tell me if i want to change anything in my encryption and decryption method or else tell me any other equivalent solution. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Encryption code:

```
bufferlen = filesize; 
buffer = new BYTE [ bufferlen ]; 
feof = false; 
do { 
    count = fread(buffer, 1, 16, filepointer); 
    if ( count < 16 ) { 
        feof = true; 
    }
    cout << count; 
    result = CryptEncrypt(hGenKey,NULL,feof,0,buffer,&count,bufferlen); 
    if ( result == 0 ) { 
        cout << "\nencrypt failed"; 
    } 
    else { 
        cout << "encrypt passed"; 
    } 
    if(fwrite(buffer, 1, count , filepointer1)!=count) { 
        cout << "\nwrite failed"; 
    }
} while (feof != true);
```

Decryption code:

```
bufferlen = filesize;
buffer = new BYTE [ bufferlen ];
feof = false;
do {
    count = fread(buffer, 1, 16, filepointer);
    if ( count < 16 ) {
        feof = true;
    }
    cout << count;
    result = CryptEncrypt(hGenKey,NULL,feof,0,buffer,&count,bufferlen);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
        cout << "\nencrypt failed";
    }
    else {
        cout << "encrypt passed";
    }
    if(fwrite(buffer, 1, count , filepointer1)!=count) {
        cout << "\nwrite failed";
    }
} while ( feof != true );
```

Comment: I would imagine showing us your algorithms might make it easier to comment on changes

Comment: ENCRYPTION:        bufferlen = filesize;
        buffer = new BYTE [ bufferlen ];
 feof = false;
 do
 {
  count = fread(buffer, 1, 16, filepointer);
  if ( count < 16 )
  {
   feof = true;
  }
  cout << count;
  result = CryptEncrypt(hGenKey,NULL,feof,0,buffer,&count,bufferlen);
  if ( result == 0 )
  {
   cout  << "\nencrypt failed";
  }
  else
  {
   cout << "encrypt passed";
  }
  if(fwrite(buffer, 1, count , filepointer1)!=count)
  {
   cout << "\nwrite failed";
  }
 } while ( feof != true ); DECRYPTION : decryption i made the above same coding instead, i kept bufferlen = filesize..

Comment: You have to use [CryptDecrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379913) to decrypt.

Comment: ECB mode is usually a bad idea - unless you know you will never encrypt the same block more than once.

Comment: @Fozi I decrypted with CryptDecrypt function only.

Comment: @Alan Ho! is it. Then please tell which mode is a good mode?

Comment: Can you then show us your decryption call please?

Comment: @Monish: It depends, but if you don't know a reason to do otherwise, I'd *generally* consider CBC as a reasonable default, with CFB as a pretty close second choice.

Comment: Here is the decryption part.. bufferlen = filesize;
 buffer = new BYTE [ bufferlen ];
 feof = false;
 do
 {
  count = fread(buffer, 1, 16, filepointer);
  if ( count < 16 )
  {
   feof = true;
  }
  cout << count;
  result = CryptDecrypt(hGenKey,NULL,feof,0,buffer,&count);
  if ( result == 0 )
  {
   cout  << "\decrypt failed";
  }
  else
  {
   cout << "\ndecrypt passed\n";
  }
  if(fwrite(buffer, 1, count , filepointer1)!=count)
  {
   cout << "\nwrite failed";
  }
 } while ( feof != true );

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Thanks for the reply. I read the modes you have mentioned in wiki. I understood the concept, can you just edit my pseudocode and show a rough pseudocode for CBC, it will be more helpful to me.

Comment: I'd go further and say that ECB mode is _always_ a bad idea.

Comment: @Monish If you don't know how to implement modes of operation, you shouldn't be implementing your own crypto code. Why not use an existing library, like KeyCzar?

Comment: @Monish: you can edit your question and add your encryption/decription code there instead of posting it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the second to last iteration of your loop, while you are doing decryption, `count` will be 16, however you have to set the [`Final`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379913) flag because it contains the padding (your `feof` is false). Then in the next iteration `count` will be 0, in which case you set `feof` but you actually have no data to decrypt any more.

Comment: Ya thank you for spotting the error, now i understood my mistake. Can you advice me any changes I have to make, in order to make the flag TRUE, while it encrypts the last block. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [feof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xssktc6e). Also, just as a note, you can pass more than one block to the encryption/decryption functions.

Comment: On second thought, feof might not work. try ftell or just read ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and for replying all my queries. I will work on it.

Comment: I tried both with feof(), i was not able stop the last loop and so i used ftell, by changing the if condition as if ( count < 16 ) to  if ( count < 16  || (ftell( filepointer ) ) == filesize){ feof = TRUE; } , this condition stops the last loop but last block fails to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the wikipedia article on ecb http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

Without at least having the pseudo code for your project there isn't much else we'll be able to say.

Comment: sorry pal cant get you. you are asking me to check the link?

Answer (score 0):

This is really an answer to a comment, not the original question. In pseudo code, CBC mode looks something like:

```
prev_block = IV;
write_output(prev_block);
current_block = first_block;

while (more blocks to process) {
    encrypted_block = encrypt_block(current_block XOR prev_block);
    write_output(encrypted_block);
    prev_block = encrypted_block;
    current_block = next_block;
}
```